# Laravel routes with multiple optional parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a RESTful api using Laravel. I am confused on how to do the routing.

**I have the following api controller**

```
class APIController extends BaseController{

    public function sendMsg($authid, $roomid, $msg){

    }

    public function getMsg($roomid, $timestamp){

    }
}
```

The URL format I want this to be accessible looks like this:
`http://example.com/api/{functionName}/{parameter1}/{parameter2}/.../`

Here, in the first parameter, I will have the function name which should map to the function in the controller class and following that the parameters the controller needs.

**For example**
 To access the `sendMsg()` function, the url should look like this:
`http://example.com/api/sendMsg/sdf879s8/2/hi+there+whats+up`

To access the `getMsg()` function, the url should look like
`http://example.com/api/getMsg/2/1395796678`

---

So... how can I write my routes so that it can handle the dynamic number and different parameters need?

I can write one route for each function name like so:

```
Route::get('/api/sendmsg/{authid}/{msg}', function($authid, $msg){
    //call function...
});
```

and same for the other function. This if fine but **is there a way to combine all function to the APIController in one route?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can combine all the function to your `APIController` in one route by using a [resourceful controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) which is best suited for building an `API`:

```
Route::resource('api' ,'APIController');
```

But, technically, it's not one route at all, instead `Laravel` generates multiple `routes` for each function, to check routes, you may run `php artisan routes` command from your command prompt/terminal.

To, create a `resourceful controller` you may run the following command from your command line:

```
php artisan controller:make APIController
```

This will create a controller with 6 functions (skeleton/structure only) and each function would be mapped to a `HTTP` verb. It means, depending on the request type (GET/POST etc) the function will be invoked. For example, if a request is made using `http://domain.com/api` using `GET` request then the `getIndex` method will be invoked.

```
public function getIndex()
{ 
    // ...
}
```

You should check the documentation for proper understanding in depth. This is known as `RESTful` api.

Comment: Your answer is interesting but it doesn't answer my question, My question is how do I map an undefined set of parameters to functions. Like function1 needs 3 parameter and function2 needs 5 parameters. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use `api/{param1?}/{param2?}` and these will be optional and your function must use a default value for each parameters like `function f($p1 = null, $p2 = null)` is that you asked for ?

Comment: Well, that could work but say if I have 4 function each with 4 unique parameters, that would be 16 parameters!. Maybe I wasn't clear enough before, is there a function that gets all the parameters in an associative array or something along those lines?

Comment: You can use `Route::current()->parameters()` to get all the parameters in an array.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for! Now one last thing. If I have a url like this `http://domain.com/api/getMsg/param1/param2/param3/` how do i make a route that responds to any url with getMsg as the first parameter

Comment: Then you have to declare a route for that using same parameters.

Comment: Try to understand `resourceful controller` this is designed for building `API` and perfect for your need.

Comment: [Antonio Carlos Ribeiro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1959747/antonio-carlos-ribeiro), thanks for the edit :-)