# Laravel route inexplicably failing

Tags: php, laravel

***This*** route will work just fine for a URL like `http://localhost:8080/promos/130-unburdened.pdf`

```
  Route::get('/{report_slug}/{report_code}{burdening_tag?}{extension?}', function($report_slug, $report_code, $burdening_tag='', $extension='') {
    return "report_slug: ${report_slug}<br>report_code: ${report_code}<br>burdening_tag: $burdening_tag<br>extension: $extension";
  });
```

***But*** if I add another optional parameter before the `{extension?}`, *which is what I really need*, **it will fail**, no matter what:

```
Route::get('/{report_slug}/{report_code}{burdening_tag?}{something?}{extension?}', function($report_slug, $report_code, $burdening_tag='', $something='', $extension='') {
    return "report_slug: ${report_slug}<br>report_code: ${report_code}<br>burdening_tag: $burdening_tag<br>extension: $extension";
  });
```

All of the optional parameters have patterns defined, so that they CANNOT match the wrong thing:

```
Route::pattern('report_code', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('burdening_tag', '(-burdened|-unburdened)');
Route::pattern('something', 'X');
Route::pattern('extension', '(\.pdf|\.xlsx|\.xls|\.csv)');
Route::pattern('report_slug',
  '(adplan|adplan-update|adplan-proof'
  .'|scandown'
  .'|promos|promo-updates'
  .'|promos-finance|promos-cost-proof'
  .'|retail-price-proof'
  .'|finance'
  .'|dsd-promos|managed-dsd-promos'
  .'|anchor-group)'
);
```

And yet one works and the other crashes and burns.  What is wrong?  Is Laravel limited to 2 optional parameters?  Is this a bug in Laravel?

Comment: Surely you can't have 2 optional parameters, at least not the way you are doing it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649764/laravel-routes-with-multiple-optional-parameters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877725/pass-many-optional-parameters-to-route-in-laravel-4

Comment: Why can't you have 2 or more optional parameters?  The patterns constrain them so Laravel ***ought*** to have no problem matching.

Comment: I'm not trying to handle an arbitrary number of unconstrained parameters, like the 2nd question.  And I'm not sure why or how the first question might be relevant.

Comment: They are both about multiple optional routes, which i thought is the same problem you are facing

Comment: Mine are very different, in that I'm specifying *exactly* what can match (and therefore what can't).  And in #1 he has 2 parameters, but I can get 2 parameters working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is an **ambiguity**: in your first route, this URL `http://localhost:8080/promos/130.pdf` should not work even if it's supposed to match the pattern.

Let me explain with a simple example:

```
Route::pattern('foo', 'A');
Route::pattern('bar', 'B');
Route::get('/test/{foo?}{bar?}',function($foo='',$bar=''){
    return "foo: $foo <br> bar: $bar";
});
// http://localhost:8080/test/AB  => work
// http://localhost:8080/test/A   => work
// http://localhost:8080/test/B   => doesn't work
```

In the third url, `foo` parameter is not empty but contains letter `B` (`bar` is empty in this case), so it doesn't match "foo pattern", hence `NotFoundHttpException`

What I try in your case (which work fine if you specify `something` parameter)

```
Route::pattern('something', 'X?');
// other patterns 
Route::get('/{report_slug}/{report_code}{burdening_tag?}{something?}{extension?}', function($report_slug, $report_code, $burdening_tag='', $something='', $extension= '') {
    return "report_slug: ${report_slug}<br>report_code: ${report_code}<br>burdening_tag: $burdening_tag <br>something: $something <br>extension: $extension ";
});
```

But if `something` parameter is not specified (like in the third example), `$extension` will be empty and `$something` will be the extension, so you have just to check if `$extension` is empty:

```
$realExtension = $extension ? $extension : $something;
```

I know it's ugly but I don't really have a good answer, maybe someone can provide a real answer.

Comment: But `$foo` ***cannot*** contain 'B' because the `Route::pattern` constrains it to 'A', so `$foo` should be NULL and `$bar` should be 'B'.  Otherwise what's the point of the pattern?  So I don't see any ambiguity. `/test/B` should match the route and give you `[$foo => NULL, $bar => 'B']`

Comment: Are you saying that an optional route cannot be matched ***if a previous optional route was not matched***?  If that were the case I think it might explain the problem, but it seems like a gaping hole in Laravel routing that doesn't make any sense.